# INNER JOIN Statement returns multiple rows instead of one

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

There are two tables, namely `sku` and `country` without any matching columns. I need to retrieve a unique field `printable_name` from country table based on the value of `c_code` in `sku` table. c_code column has multiple same country codes(Example: 124) while numcode column in the country table contains the same country code but only once because it is a unique field. The row that has the unique numcode has the country name which I am finally trying to retrieve. The result from my SQL query below gives multiple rows instead of just one from the country table. I just want one record only from country table, which is `printable_name`

I am trying to combine the following SQLs into one with the JOIN statement.

```
$vendor_sku = $my_line_item['sku'];
                        
                        // Build SQL to retrieve country name.
                        $sql = "SELECT c_code FROM sku WHERE item_sku = '" . $vendor_sku . "'";
                        $sql = "SELECT printable_name FROM country WHERE numcode = '" . $c_code . "'";

SELECT country.printable_name
  FROM country INNER JOIN sku ON country.numcode = sku.c_code
 WHERE country.numcode = "124"
```

Part of my country table is :

[image]

part of sku table is:

[image]

Country table has only one entry for numcode 124 as seen below.
[image]

Comment: it can happen when sku table has multiple same c_code for country num_code.

Comment: add a `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` to filter out the duplicates

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please see the table images added to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT a.printable_name
  FROM country a
 WHERE
 1=1
 and a.numcode = '124'
 and exists (select 1 from sku s where a.numcode = s.c_code)
```

Comment: @Mizab, perfect. This returned just one field which I wanted. I would like this to be simplified if possible. I am still a beginner at SQL. Thanks

Comment: @CodeForGood. Glad I could help. I would not recommend using joins in your, case because, you are risking multiplying rows, when there will be more then one record in sku table with c_code = '124'. Exists is function is efficient solution, worth knowing. It is checking if there are any rows in sku table where a.numcode = s.c_code.  I am selecting 1 instead of any specific column, because it dosen't effect the function result - I am just checking if there are any rows which are matching my condition.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want the record only from country table

Then why are you using the `sku` table?

```
SELECT c.printable_name
FROM country c
WHERE c.numcode = 124;
```

Note:  I assume that 124 is a *number*, so I removed the quotes.  If it is a string, then use a string with single quotes, `'124'`.

Comment: OP's query also checks that at least one relative row exists in `sku`...

Comment: @Akina . . . I actually want the OP to explain that.  It is not clear (to me at least) in the question that is asked.

Comment: Please check my updated post to get better understanding of what I am trying to do. I am basically trying to combine two SQL statements into one using JOIN.

Comment: @CodeForGood . . . If you want the name of the country with code 124, you don't need the `sku` table.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. The code 124 is an hardcoded number for the purpose testing. This country code is earlier retrieved from sku table.